# BCM43XX WiFi driver in Debian Wheezy

Tags: wireless-networking, debian, broadcom, wifi-driver, debian-wheezy

The described method to get the WiFi working under Debian Wheezy (Broadcom BCM43XX) in the [Debian Wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/wl#Wheezy) worked for me… yesterday.

After rebooting the computer (Lenovo IdeaPad S10 netbook)  there is no `eth1` available anymore. Unloading possibly loaded wrong drivers with `modprobe` and reloading the broadcom drivers (`modprobe wl`) didn't help.

Neither did doing all the steps described in the Debian Wiki again.

the WLAN module is on and recognized (`lspci`).

Comment: I have the same wireless card, look at that question, it has no answer but maybe could help you: http://superuser.com/questions/378739/linux-and-wifi-on-hp-6735s. I try to explain, it seemst that the broadcom card has some problems with linux and sometimes it turend off itself you can try:
1. if you have windows to log-in in windows see if your card is turned on, if yes try to boot on linux, if not turn it on and boot on linux. Or you can simply try to press the wireless card button in the early phases of boot process, sometimes you must try many times. At least for me it works :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `modprobe b43` not `modprobe wl` if you have a Broadcom card that is supported by the BCM43XX driver.

I have one card of that series. Things are working just fine for me, but I have to modeprobe manually every time. The driver is not loading automatically. The rest is working fine though.